# Return dymanic object from WCF to AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, wcf

I have a function in `WCF` should return (to ajax request) class / class that inherits:

```
public User GetUserData(string username, string password)
{
   return bl.GetUserData(username, password);
}
```

The function returns an object of type User / object of type Manager (a class that inherits from User).

**When `User` returns, everything works great!**

When returns `Manager` I get the following error message (on console):

```
POST http://localhost:xxx/Service.svc/GetUserData net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

If I return `Manager` in a separate function it works! So the problem is not the class.

**The problem is probably the signature of the function.**

I tried to change my signature so that the function returns `Object / dynamic`, nothing helped. The error still appears.

Anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Tried using [KnownType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @Flowerking, I tried, did not help!